# Narrowing column margins (inside)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a portfolio wordpress website that utilizes bootstrap 3. It is basically an image grid.  When the screen expands it goes from three columns to four. When mobile it is one single column.

I figured out how to adjust the top and bottom margins of the images, but I want the images closer together on the sides. This means I assume adjusting the margins between the columns. The page uses

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
```

Where is the code to change the bootstrap margins. Is it possible to do it in my '.styles' or 'functions' files (since it is a child theme)?

Comment: you can add your own class to this and set the marin level as per your need: ex: <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 myClass"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the padding each side is `15px` if you haven't customized you bootstrap:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, ... {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

As long as your `css` file is inserted after the `bootstrap.css` you can add the following:

```
[class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

**Note:** this will override the gap for the whole website.

Alternatively you can build bootstrap for your needs using http://getbootstrap.com/customize/